# Recursive parsing of hierarchical Twig layout with parents, children, grandchildren

Tags: symfony, macros, twig, hierarchy

In my SF2 project I have an entity (Category) which I am representing in a hierarchical format with a parent at the top, followed by children, grandchildren etc.

The Category entity has a `getChildren` method, which works and returns `Category` entity objects.

I'm trying to work out a way to make this layout more dynamic, rather than having to explicitly set `children` and `grandchildren` variables within the template.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
<ul class="sortable">
    {% for cat in cats %}
        {% set children = cat.getChildren %}
        <li id="menuItem_{{ cat.id }}">
            <div data-id="{{ cat.id }}">
                <span>{{ cat.name }}</span>
            </div>
            {% for child in children %}
                {% set grandchildren = child.getChildren %}
                <ul>
                    <li id="menuItem_{{ child.id }}">
                        <div data-id="{{ child.id }}">
                            {{ child.name }}
                        </div>
                        {% for grandchild in grandchildren %}
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menuItem_{{ grandchild.id }}">
                                    <div data-id="{{ grandchild.id }}">
                                        {{ grandchild.name }}
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what you are trying to achieve is recursive parsing of a tree in twig right?
If so, have a look at [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)
.

```
{% import _self as macros %}

{% macro showChild(object) %}
  {% import _self as macros %}
  <ul>
    {% for child in object.children %}
      {{ macros.showChild(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    <li id="menuItem_{{ object.id }}">
      <div data-id="{{ object.id }}">
        {{ object.name }}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
{% endmacro %}

<ul class="sortable">
  {% for cat in cats %}
    {{ macros.showChild(cat) }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

that's all :)
let me know if you need help

**EDIT 1:**
If you want to use the macro in another file, remove the "import _self" line and just import it with an alias in another file:

```
index.html.twig:
{% import 'macro_file_name.html.twig' as macros %}
```

then you can use the same notation to call it

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm seeing an Exception in my application when using it. Here's a pastebin of my code - is it obvious what I have done incorrect? http://pastebin.com/xvvyv3ma

Comment: I don't really know how importing a macro works, but my best guess is that "import ... **as tree_children**" overwrites your tree_children variable. Try importing without an alias. If that doesn't work, try using the macro in the same file.

Comment: Great, thank you. I had to add the `{% import _self as macros %}` inside the macro. I've updated and accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.